# Why "unable to resolve dependency tree" related to peer is thrown and how to fix it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm

In my React Native application, I want to install React Native Firebase Auth module with this command:

```
npm install --save @react-native-firebase/auth
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: woo@0.0.1
npm ERR! Found: @react-native-firebase/app@14.12.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app
npm ERR!   @react-native-firebase/app@"^14.11.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @react-native-firebase/app@"16.5.0" from @react-native-firebase/auth@16.5.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@react-native-firebase/auth
npm ERR!   @react-native-firebase/auth@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

My packaje.json file:

```json
"react-native": "0.68.2",
"@react-native-firebase/app": "^14.11.1",
"@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^14.11.1",
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Explanation

If you install `@react-native-firebase/auth` in a separate folder after an `npm init -y`, and open its folder by looking into `node_modules`, you would see in its `package.json` this:

```json
"peerDependencies": {
  "@react-native-firebase/app": "16.5.0"
},
```

It means that it needs version `16.5.0` of `@react-native-firebase/app` in order to work, while you, in your `package.json`, have version `14.11.1`; this is the problem.

But the thing is that `@react-native-firebase/messaging` version `14.11.1` needs the version `14.12.0` of  `@react-native-firebase/app`, as it has in its `package.json`:

```json
 "peerDependencies": {
   "@react-native-firebase/app": "14.12.0"
 },
```

## Solution

The solution is to find versions that would make all of them agree. In your specific case, one way would be first to upgrade both of them to their latest versions:

```json
npm i --save @react-native-firebase/messaging@latest @react-native-firebase/app@latest
```

And then, install `@react-native-firebase/auth`:

```
npm i --save @react-native-firebase/auth
```