# Could not resolve dependency: npm ERR! @tensorflow-models/mobilenet@"*" from the root project

Tags: reactjs, npm, tensorflow.js, mobilenet

I tried to install `@tensorflow-models/mobilenet` using `npm install @tensorflow-models/mobilenet`. But following error popped up.

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: undefined@undefined
npm ERR! Found: @tensorflow/tfjs-converter@4.1.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-converter
npm ERR!   @tensorflow/tfjs-converter@"4.1.0" from @tensorflow/tfjs@4.1.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs
npm ERR!     @tensorflow/tfjs@"^4.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   @tensorflow/tfjs-converter@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! @tensorflow-models/mobilenet@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @tensorflow/tfjs-converter@3.21.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-converter
npm ERR!   peer @tensorflow/tfjs-converter@"^3.1.0" from @tensorflow- 
models/mobilenet@2.1.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@tensorflow-models/mobilenet
npm ERR!     @tensorflow-models/mobilenet@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! /home/thesilentguy/.npm/_logs/2022-12-30T19_26_56_164Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/thesilentguy/.npm/_logs/2022-12-30T19_26_56_164Z-debug-0.log
```

How to install this `@tensorflow-models/mobilenet`? Please help.

Comment: Cany you show your package.json?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree is thrown and how to resolve it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74901830/why-err-eresolve-unable-to-resolve-dependency-tree-is-thrown-and-how-to-resolve)