# Installing multiple versions of React with NPM

Tags: reactjs, npm, react-dom

Long story short, I currently have React 16 installed and I wanted to add React 17 to check tests, migrate, etc.
Running `npm install` throws an error, because react-dom@17 requires react@17 and it seems to not being able to find one.
The question is - is there a way to fix this problem without using --force or --legacy-peer-deps flags?

I created aliased packages, using [react-redux](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/package.json#L116-L119) as an example.

```
"react": "^16.8.6",
"react-17": "npm:react@^17",
"react-dom": "^16.8.6",
"react-dom-17": "npm:react-dom@^17"
```

Running `npm install` throws an error, because react-dom@17 requires react@17 and it seems to not being able to find one.

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: platform-modules@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: react@16.14.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   dev react@"^16.8.6" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"npm:react@^17" from react-dom-17@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react-dom-17
npm ERR!   dev react-dom-17@"npm:react-dom@^17" from the root project
```

I tried using npm overrides, as well as peerDependenciesMeta but it unfortunately didn't help.

```
  "overrides": {
    "react-dom-17": {
      "react": "$react-17"
    }
  },
  "peerDependenciesMeta": {
    "react-dom": {
      "optional": true
    }
  }
```

react-redux package uses this approach, but it uses Yarn instead of NPM.

Comment: Does this help understand why this error? [Why ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree is thrown and how to resolve it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74901830/why-err-eresolve-unable-to-resolve-dependency-tree-is-thrown-and-how-to-resolve)

Comment: There is little to no migration involved. Why not just update to 17 directly?

Comment: @yousoumar I know how peerDependencies work and how this error is thrown. In the usual cases, I would just have to follow the error and update my react to the corresponding version. However, as I mentioned, the problem is that I want to have two versions of react in the project, and react-dom@17 seems to ignore, that there is a react@17 being installed.

Comment: @vighnesh153 its more of a "can i do this" than "should i do this" situation